# magento 2 How to make a custom shipping address field required on checkout page?

Tags: magento2, shipping-address, checkout-page

I have created a custom shipping address field which is dropdown select and shows on checkout page. 
While creating attribute I wrote their  `required => true`

but it is not working. I am able to save address without input in that field. Please guide me.

**InstallData.php**

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'industry_type', [
            'label' => 'Industry Type',
            'input' => 'select',
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table',
            'required' => true,
            'position' => 333,
            'visible' => true,
            'system' => false,
            'is_used_in_grid' => false,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
            'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
            'backend' => '',
            'option' =>
            array (
                'values' =>
                    array (
                        0 => 'Federal Government',
                        1 => 'State Government',
                        2 => 'Local Government',
                        3 => 'K through 12',
                        4 => 'Higher Education',
                        5 => 'Non Profit',
                        6 => 'Government Health Ca',
                        7 => 'Private Hospital',
                        8 => 'Doctor\'s Office',
                        9 => 'Teaching Hospital',
                        10 => 'None',
                        11 => 'Commercial',
                    ),
            ),
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this Magento Dev Docs link - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html

You would need to add it like this -

```
'validation' => [
   'required-entry' => true
],
```

Comment: please check my updated question. I am only using this code in installdata.

Comment: Just being a bit catchy, Could you try removing this node 'required' and see if the db table eav_attribute gets is_required 1? 
The default value for required is 1(bool true)

Comment: ok I will try and let you know if it works.

Comment: temper how did it go?